# how to convert user input of string to object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to convert user input of string  to object 
assume that i have array of string

`["code:213123", "code:213123", "code:213123"]`

how to  convert it to array of obj
so the result should be like this:

`[{code: "213123"},...]`

Comment: Where is the `input`, what is the expected input and where is the source code that you have tried to add the new entry?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorila service. You are expected to show what you have tried to solve issues yourself

Comment: I work on react.js the input is <textarea> and i have <buttin> on cklick shoud give  array of object : handleClick = () => { 
    let obj = {}
    const KeyVal = this.state.couponCodes.split('\n')
    for (let i in KeyVal) {
      KeyVal[i] = KeyVal[i].split(":");
      obj[KeyVal[i][0]] = KeyVal[i][1];
    }
    console.log(obj);
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question, assuming the user enters text strictly in the format `code: x code: y code: z` available to you as a string, you may do something like:

```
`code: 2a31sdd23
code: asdw12ds3
code: 213sad123`
.replace(/[\r\n]*/g,'')
.replace(/code:\s+/g,'')
.replace(/[\s\t]+/g,' ')
.split(' ')
.reduce((p,c) => {p.push({code: c}); return p}, [])

// Output
// [{code: "2a31sdd23"}, {code: "asdw12ds3"}, {code: "213sad123"}]
```

Comment: that good but the input is new line after each code: 2a31sdd23

Comment: in your code take it as one element `0: code: "2a31sdd23↵asdw12ds3↵213sad123"`

Comment: In that case you need another `replace` before the existing one to remove line breaks. Try:

`.replace(/[\r\n]*/g,'').replace(/code:\s+/g,'')

Comment: the same give me one arg. `0: {code: "code:123123code:123123code:123123"}`

Answer (score 1):

`new Function` or `eval` can convert like this:

```js
let params = '["code:213123", "code:213123", "code:213123"]';
params = new Function(`return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(${params}));`)();
```